# Not able to access .css file in FTL for PDF generation

Tags: css

I want to access .css file in FTL for generating PDF but I not able to see the effect in PDF.

I tried both ways

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../font/fonts.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/global.css"/>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/font/fonts.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/global.css"/>
```

My folder location is, and Currently, I am using Liferay DXP

```
META-INF/resources/font/fonts.css
META-INF/resources/stylesheets/global.css
```

code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="key, words"/>    
    <meta name="description" content="Website description"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
     maximum-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../font/fonts.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/global.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<section id="wrapper">
    <section id="mainCntr">
        <article class="objectBox">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src=""/>
            </div>
                <div class="text">
                <h2>Objects in <br/> this document <br/> are simpler <br/> than they seem.</h2>
            </div>
        </article>

    </section>
 </section>
 </body>

</html>
```

Can anybody tell me the right approach to get effect *fonts.css* and *global.css* in FTL to generate PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we applied inline CSS for whole pdf file code on each and every lines as per our requirements.

Remove below to lines from the pdf file code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../font/fonts.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/global.css"/>
```